# JQuery Validation Engine with knockout and bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, jquery-validation-engine

I am using bootstrap and knockout in my project . Before now i was using knockout validation , but now i have to use jquery validation engine with knockout view models and bootstrap html . Suppose this is my html

```
<fieldset>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control placeholder" id="personName" placeholder="Your name" data-bind="value: name" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control placeholder" id="personEmail" placeholder="Your email" data-original-title="Your activation email will be sent to this address." data-bind="value: email, event: { change: checkDuplicateEmail }" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control placeholder" id="password" placeholder="Password" data-bind="value: password" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="confirmPassword">Repeat Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control placeholder" id="repeatPassword" placeholder="Repeat password" data-bind="value: confirmPassword, event: { change: matchPassword }" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="companyName">Company Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control placeholder" id="companyName" placeholder="Your company name" data-bind="value: company" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="country">Country</label>
        <select class="form-control placeholder" id="country" data-bind="options: availableCountries, value: selectedCountry, optionsCaption: 'Country'"></select>
    </div>
    <button id="signupuser" type="button" data-bind="click: signup" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Create Free Account</button>
</fieldset>
```

now i am confused about how to use [jQuery Validation Engine Plugin](http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/demos/demoValidators.html)  with my above code .

Comment: Are you confused with which part? What have you tried so far? How is your view model looks like? What do you want to validate?

Comment: I am confused that how to use this plugin because i don't have `form` element in my markup .

Comment: Then why don't you wrap your `fieldset` into a `form`?

Comment: Yes , i know this could work if i wrap fieldset into form but is there any other way to do this without form ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally got solution in [demos](http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/demos/demoValidators.html) , wrap fieldset into a div

```
<div id="formID">
<fieldset>
// all input elements here 
</fieldset>
</div>
```

In **JS**

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#formID").validationEngine();
        $(".submit").click(function () {
            $("#formID").validationEngine('validate');
        })
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all i highly suggest you read the [documentation](http://posabsolute.github.io/jQuery-Validation-Engine/) so you can get better understanding of how to implement validation.

That's **[Working Demo](http://jsbin.com/owUMUFe/2/edit)** to validate your form.

For example to make your input required all what you need to use is

```
<input type="text" id="name" class="validate[required]" />
```

To make your input valid email:

```
<input type="text" id="email" class="validate[required,custom[email]]" />
```